# Create dynamic post mapping in Spring boot like Spring Data rest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I wan to create some thing similar how Spring data rest create dynamic POST,GET,PATCH.. etc dynamically.(I think those are generated on run-time).
I have the scenario where some POST and GET controllers to created on run-time.

Manully created controllers will be like,

```
@PostMapping(value = "/{id}/images")
    public ResponseEntity<?> setProfileImage(@PathVariable(value = "id", required = true) Long id,
            @RequestParam(value = "images", required = true) MultipartFile file[], Principal principal,
            HttpServletRequest request) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(this.localFileSaver.save(request, file));
    }
```